# losing the first result of retrieved data when binding it to repeater control

Tags: asp.net, repeater, sqldatareader

I am developing a social network in which i must show a list of friends to the current user.

i am using SqlDataReader to retrieve data from database then bind it by a repeater , the problem is that the repeater always skip the first result so it only shows the n-1 results out of n. anybody can explain to me this behaviour?

my code is:

```
string cmdstr2 = "SELECT students.fname, students.lname,students.username FROM students INNER JOIN friends ON students.username = friends.tostudent WHERE (friends.fromstudent ='" + cuser + "')";

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(cmdstr2, sc);
SqlDataReader rd = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

if (rd.Read())
        {

            Repeater1.DataSource = rd;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
```

in the design view, i have written this code to include the repeater in the page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <div style="font-size:xx-large;">
                                        الأصدقاء</div>

                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                          <div style="font-size:x-large; color:Black; margin-right:0px; margin-top:0px;">
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 

                                        NavigateUrl='<%# "student.aspx?user="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"username")%>' >

                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fname")%>&nbsp;<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "lname")%>
                </asp:HyperLink>
                                    </div>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **rd.Read()** in your if statement is advancing it 1 record

Try using:

```
if (rd.HasRows)
```